# Add new row onkeyup inside last input field

Tags: javascript

imagine i have 3 rows in a table, there is 3 input fields in every row. when i type something in the last input field it should add new row following that last row also when i hit backspace and all fields in latest row is empty then the new added row should be remove

i have no idea how to prevent another addition if the new row already appended to the table. this is what i've done so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=class_name\\[\\]]:last-child").keyup(function addNewRow(e){
        var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
        var tr = parent.clone();
        if(e.keyCode != 8){
            $("#classes tr:last-child").remove();
        }else{
            $("#classes").append(tr);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how about a check by selecting the last element again, and compare it to `this`? If it's not the same, then a row has already been added

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```
    <table id="classes">
        <tr>
            <td><input onchange="process()"/></td><td><input onchange="process()"/></td><td><input onchange="process()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input onchange="process()"/></td><td><input onchange="process()"/></td><td><input onchange="process()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input onchange="process()"/></td><td><input onchange="process()"/></td><td><input onchange="process()"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Javascript:

```
        function process(){
            var parent = $("#classes tr:last-child").closest('tr');
            var tr = parent.clone();
            if($("#classes tr:last-child td:last-child input").val() !== '')
            {
                $("#classes").append(tr);
            }
            else if($("#classes tr:last-child td").eq(0).find("input").val() === '' && $("#classes tr:last-child td").eq(1).find("input").val() === '' && $("#classes tr:last-child td").eq(2).find("input").val() === '')
            {
                $("#classes tr:last-child").remove();
            }
        }
```